# use invalidateOptionsMenu inside BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I've searched the net for answers but wasn't able to find a solution I need. My question is how do I recreate the menu again to update my cart count icon inside my `BaseAdapter`. The app I'm working right now is an app that count the items a user ordered, it also has item categories. When I go back to the activity that displays the categories, the cart updates but I can't do it in my item adapter. the code is very simple.

This line is at the end of ordering the item.

```
setNotifCount(db.getCartCount());
```

and this is the function.

```
private void setNotifCount(int count){
         mNotifCount = count;
         invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

It shows that `invalidateOptionsMenu();` is an error because it cannot resolve that method. i tried using ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu() but it also throws an NPE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant call invalidateOptionsMenu() as there is no such method in base adapter. What you can do is pass your activity as context to base adapter and call as below.

```
        ((YourActivity)context).invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Also calling ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu() will through NPE as you are calling invalidateOptionsMenu on a class and not an object.